# Return a column value if XML column contain a certain value

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have this table where we have 3 rows

```
ID    LOCATION    PhoneNo    XML 
1        NY         123    xmlfile1
2        CA         322    xmlfile2
3        MA         151    xmlfile3
4        WA         111    xmlfile4
```

assume xmlfile1 and 2 looks similar

```
<shop>
   <item>
       <Product>shirt</Product>
       <color>red</color>
   </item>
   <item>
       <Product>shirt</Product>
       <color>yellow</color>
   </item>
   <item>
       <Product>jeans</Product>
       <color>blue</color>
   </item>
</shop>
```

I do cross apply to find the colors if the product was shirts using this,

```
 SELECT P.I.value('color[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS shirt_color
 FROM myTable t
 CROSS APPLY t.[XML].nodes('/shop/item[contains(Product[1], "shirt")]') as P(I)
```

it gives me a nice table with the colors

```
 shirt_color
     red
   yellow
     red
   yellow
```

, but I want it also to return the LOCATION and PHONENo which is in the same row.like this

```
 shirt_color    Location    PhoneNo
     red           NY         123
   yellow          NY         123
     red           CA         322
   yellow          CA         322
```

So basically if the conditions met for XML find me columns in the same row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just specify them on the SELECT line:

```
 SELECT P.I.value('color[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS shirt_color,
        LOCATION as Location, PhoneNo
 FROM myTable t
 CROSS APPLY t.[XML].nodes('/shop/item[contains(Product[1], "shirt")]') as P(I)
```